# Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9505 firmware update issue

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung, stock-android, samsung-kies

I was updating the firmware of my Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9505 with Samsung Kies 3 on my Macintosh and suddenly my laptop turned off, so I disconnect the phone and tried to reboot it and after it displayed the following message on its screen:

> Firmware upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in Kies & try again.

Also on top left of the screen there is some text being displayed in the tiniest readable font it seems, which says:

> ODIN MODE
>
> PRODUCT NAME: GT-I9505
>
> CURRENT BINARY: SAMSUNG OFFICIAL
>
> SYSTEM STATUS: OFFICIAL
>
> KNOX KERNEL LOCK: 0x0
>
> KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 0x0
>
> CSB-CONFIG-LSB: 0x30
>
> WRITE PROTECTION: ENABLE
>
> eMMC BRUST MODE enabled

Since, the laptop turned off in the middle of the update, when I restarted it Samsung Kies 3 had no idea what happened and now my phone won't even show up in the Firmware emergency recovery window of Kies 3. Firmware upgrade and initialization also doesn’t work since ‘GT-I9505’ doesn't support initializing.

Can anybody help me?

P.S: My cell phone isn't rooted or anything. I don't have any custom recovery installed. I was just using the official Samsung ROM and OTA updates whenever they arrive.

Comment: Seems like you have to Odin your phone back to life...

Comment: Yes I did that and now it is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to repair your phone with Odin 3.07.

**THIS WILL VOID YOUR WARRANTY!**

1. Go to [www.sammobile.com](http://www.sammobile.com)
2. Then go to firmwares.
3. Search the right firmware for your device.
4. Download Odin (do a google search).
5. Extract Odin.zip
6. Put the md5/tar in the PA/PDA slot.
7. Click on start/begin/OK.
8. Wait a few minutes and your will reboot.

Comment: Could you explain some more detail about it? What to do using Odin?

Comment: @AndrewT. Updated answer!